# How to setup proxy in Emacs which rquires authentification to download packages from melpa?

Tags: package-repositories, proxy

I try to setup a corporate proxy in Emacs:

in Bash I've setup the following environment variables:

```bash
export http_proxy="http://my_login:my_psw@192.168.100.1:8080";export https_proxy="http://my_login:my_psw@192.168.100.1:8080";export ftp_proxy="http://my_login:my_psw@192.168.100.1:8080
```

-> wget, curl, git worked fine with this setting,
unfortunately Emacs doesn't.

I tried to reproduce this with a setup of tinyproxy at home:

without authentication:

here the `tinyproxy.conf`

```
Port 8080
Listen 192.168.100.1
Timeout 600
Allow 192.168.100.1/24
```

Emacs uses the proxy for melpa with this settings in my `.emacs`-file:

```lisp
(setq url-proxy-services
   '(("no_proxy" . "^\\(localhost\\|10\\..*\\|192\\.168\\..*\\)")
    ("http" . "192.168.100.1:8080")
    ("https" . "192.168.100.1:8080")))
```

but as far I use authentication:

I got following error:`Proxy authentication required`

here my  `tinyproxy.conf`:

```
Port 8080
Listen 192.168.100.1
Timeout 600
Allow 192.168.100.1/24
BasicAuth my_login my_psw
```

I have no idea how to setup the authentication method in Emacs.

an [old post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787087/use-elpa-emacs-behind-a-proxy-requiring-authentication)
suggests to add:

```lisp
(setq url-http-proxy-basic-auth-storage
    (list (list "192.168.100.1:8080"
                (cons "Input your LDAP UID !"
                      (base64-encode-string "my_login:my_psw")))))
```

but it doesn't work (same error:`Proxy authentication required`)

Any suggestion or help how to debug the problem is welcome.

Comment: Would it help to say why/how the SO suggestion "doesn't work"? Would that make clearer what's wrong?

Comment: @Drew: I've added the SO suggestion. Is there maybe a way to debug if the introduced variable `url-http-proxy-basic-auth-storage` is used somewhere?

Comment: No idea. But I'm guessing that you're meant to insert strings that correspond to what those strings describe, not to insert those strings literally.